# Split a <div> filled with an image into several small <div> and add html elements using html, css and js

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, svg

I have a seat position image from the client. I use an image from google to illustrate.
[image]

Due to the requirement, I cannot totally design it from scratch using html element but only use the seat distribution image from the client. The format of the image is svg so that in the case of window maximzing it won't lose resolution.

What I try to do is firstly to fill a `<div>` with the image as background. Inside the `<div>`, I will divide it into several sections, like the yellow part and other parts with blue and white background. In the yellow part I'd like to add a combobox, inside which a list of checkboxes and a text input exist. Position like red and green square will be replaced with checkboxes.

To extend the project in the future. We may get different types of image, each of which has different design. I'm thinking to store design data into `json` file and load the file after requirement.

What confuses me is if it is possible to divide one `<div>` into several `sub-<div>` based on the design mentioned above. Since the image is svg, how to make the cutting suitable for changing the size of the browser (window).

I'm refering to some seat position selection tutorials online, but they all design the seats from scratch.

Is my design possible to realize? Could someone give me some advices or tell me which techs I should follow?

Comment: Can't a ``<map>``  element do the work for you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: You could just use your client's image as the background to a div and measure the % distances of each seat in relation to that image - no need to worry about scale as long as you measure everything in the same units. Then when someone clicks on the div you can easily work out which seat (if any) they are in and you'll know its dimensions. I wouldn't bother having an element for each seat, too messy and not needed.

Comment: You can dynamically create this using `<svg>` elements which are clickable, instead of `<div>`s. Maybe what you want in future is a program that'll create `<svg>` element based on an svg image. Maybe such a thing already exist